# Question about probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable on $(\Omega, S, P)$, where $\Omega$ is a set and $S$ is a sigma-algebra and $P$ is a probability measure.
Define $P_{X}\colon \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})\to [0,1]$ is defined as for each Borel set
$P_{X}(B)$=$P(X^{-1}(B))$=$P$({$w\in \Omega$ such that $X(\omega)\in B$ }), Where $b$ is a Borel set,
I have to prove that $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}),P_{X})$ is a probability space.What I know is that $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is a sigma-algebra and we have a set $\mathbb{R}$ so we just have to prove that $P_{X}$ is a probability measure, it is clear that $P_{X}(\phi)=0$ and $P_{X}(\mathbb{R})=1$ now we have to prove that if $\{B_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be collection of disjoint Borel sets then $P_{X}(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{i})$=$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P_{X}(B_i)$

Comment: Can you write down in symbols what you're supposed to show for countable additivity? Proving this should be just as trivial once you know what the preimage $X^{-1}$ does to a union of sets.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I have updated the question , please have a lpok.

Comment: I am sure this question has been answered here already @AmitVis

Comment: Now, write the definitions of both sides of your last equation. Again, this is pretty much just a check of whether or not you understand the definitions of the symbols involved. Anyway, a simple google search gives [Pushforward Measure is Measure](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pushforward_Measure_is_Measure) (see their verification of axiom 2).